# How to use WP Team's MediaViewer class to display 150+ images?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, media

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app. It's basically an image viewer with support of zoom. User can swipe left & right to switch the image. I also want to add index input so user can jump to that particular image. I was searching & came across a NuGet package called [PhoneMediaViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneMediaViewer). There's also MSDN sample called [Basic Lens sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b) which uses that media viewer. I checked the code & I am not getting the code. Any please help me out about how can I display local 150+ images with zoom support it that media viewer control.

Comment: I've toyed with it when I first saw this class. Maybe you can get some more details when looking at my test project? https://github.com/Depechie/ImageSliderMediaClass

Answer (score 4):

The Windows Phone programming itself can be difficult, with a deep understanding of the new async, await keywords being a necessity for even noob tutorials.  Then again, working with the Phones local file system, ie. IsolatedStorage will take a decent understanding of Streams to get you up and going.  .Net has generally done a Great Job of taking care of most of this work for you, however in Windows Phone you are definitely on your own to handle these tasks.

To work with the MediaViewer control, you should simply install the Nuget Package to the Project you are working on.  Then you will want to supply a List of IThumbnailedImage to the MediaViewer controls Items property.  The nuget comes with two classes that implement this interface, LocalFolderThumbnailedImage and MediaLibraryThumbnailedImage, where the first is used for local Images stored on the Phone, ie. IsolatedStorage, and the later is for Image items in your Media Library.  To use the MediaLibraryThumbnailedImage class make sure you have allowed the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO Capability in the WMAppManifest.xml file or else no Albums will be returned in your calls.

However if you want to work with Images that are available online you will have to implement another class.  I called mine OnlineMediaThumbnailedImage.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace MobileWin8Phone.ImageItem
{
    class OnlineMediaThumbnailedImage : IThumbnailedImage
    {
        private Stream _stream;
        private string _imageUrl;

        /// <summary>
        /// This class implements the IThumbnailedImage interface so that it can be
        /// consumed by the MediaViewer control.  Obtain the Stream of an image and
        /// pass it in so that the MediaViewer control can call GetImage() when needed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="theImageStream"></param>
        /// <param name="imageUrl"></param>
        public OnlineMediaThumbnailedImage(Stream theImageStream, string imageUrl = "")
        {
            _stream = theImageStream;
            _imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a Stream representing the thumbnail image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Stream of the thumbnail image.</returns>
        public Stream GetThumbnailImage()
        {
            return this._stream;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a Stream representing the full resolution image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Stream of the full resolution image.</returns>
        public Stream GetImage()
        {
            return this._stream;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the time the photo was taken, useful for sorting photos.
        /// </summary>
        public System.DateTime DateTaken
        {
            get
            {
                return System.DateTime.Today;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The caller of this class is responsible for getting a Stream of the Image that they want to display.  Since we are working with the Windows Phone all calls should be marked Async so that they can run to completion and allow the UI thread to return to processing as soon as possible.  Here is sample code from a Page I used to house my MediaViewer control.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Initialize Items
    List<IThumbnailedImage> theImages = new List<IThumbnailedImage>();
    mvControl.Items = new ObservableCollection<object>(theImages);

    //Begin downloading images.
    await LoadImages();
}

private async Task LoadImages()
{
    try
    {
        await LoadFromOnlineMedia();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string pauseHere = "";
    }
}

private async Task LoadFromOnlineMedia()
{
    await DownloadImageFile("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png");
    await DownloadImageFile("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgba.png");
    await DownloadImageFile("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pngtest16rgba.png");
}

private async Task DownloadImageFile(string imageUrl)
{
    WebClient theClient = new WebClient();
    theClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
    theClient.OpenReadAsync(new System.Uri(imageUrl));
}

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Add Image to the Items collection via the UI Thread.
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { mvControl.Items.Add(new OnlineMediaThumbnailedImage(e.Result)); });
}
```

When the Page is Navigated to we enter the OnNavigatedTo method.  This method is marked as async so that we can call and await other async methods inside of it.  We start by creating an empty List and initializing the mvController.Items collection.  This is ok to do here since we are still on the Main UI Thread.

Next we await our call to Load the images so it can go off and do its thing and the UI thread can return to capturing User Interactions.  The LoadOnlineMedia method uses WebClients to Read the Image Stream from the given URL.  A callback is used for this function since again, this is Windows Phone programming and all Network Calls must be Asynchronous.  If we omit the await keyword, the async methods will be run Synchronously and any network calls will not be processed.

Basically your Callback methods will never be hit for any of your WebClient calls if you are calling from the UI thread.

Once the callbacks are hit, we use the returned Stream to build an OnlineMediaThumbnailedImage.  We use the Dispatcher to call BeginInvoke to add this item to the Items collection because any thing done to the UI or UI collections must be done back on the UI thread.

The Dispatcher automatically returns to the UI thread to complete its work, regardless of what thread it is called from.  Once we add the item to the collection the MediaViewer control will use Virtulization to decide when to load an image.  Basically it loads the first ~5 images and continues to load more as they come into range.  When the MediaViewer is ready to load an Image it calls GetImage or GetThumbnailImage to return a Stream of the Image that is to be viewed.  If you wish to overwrite IThumbnailImage with your own class just remember to override these methods and supply the Image stream in any way you see fit.